# i get random unicode characters in my json file when i decrypt it

Tags: c#, json, encryption

i'm making an aes encryption for my save file but i get random unicode characters in my json file when i decrypt it

`{"s➴uls":1800.0}` when decrypted

`{"souls":1800.0}` (what i expected)

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System;

public static class Save
{
    public static void SaveStats () 
    {
        PlayerData data = new PlayerData();

        string savedPlayerData = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);

        string encrypteddata = EncryptFratamus(savedPlayerData);

        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/DDGS1_data.json";

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) 
        {
            writer.Write(encrypteddata);
        }
    }

    public static PlayerData LoadPlayer() 
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/DDGS1_data.json";

        if (File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            string savedPlayerData;


            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path)) 
            {
                savedPlayerData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            string decryptdata = DecryptFratamus(savedPlayerData);

            PlayerData data = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerData>(decryptdata);

            return data;
        } else 
        {
            Debug.Log("ERROR CODE #0 \n Savefile not found at" + path); 
            return null;
        }
    }

    static byte[] IVbytes = new byte[16];
    static byte[] KEYbytes = new byte[16];

    static void GenerateIVByets() 
    {
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        rnd.NextBytes(IVbytes);

        Debug.Log(IVbytes);
    }

    static void GenerateKeys() 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (char charr in "i ain't giving you the key")
            sum += charr;

        System.Random rnd = new System.Random(sum);
        rnd.NextBytes(KEYbytes);
    }

    public static string EncryptFratamus(string data)
    {
        GenerateIVByets();
        GenerateKeys();

        SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = Aes.Create();
        ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(KEYbytes, IVbytes);
        byte[] inputbuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);
        byte[] outputbuffer = transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputbuffer, 0, inputbuffer.Length);

        string IVstring = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(IVbytes);
        string encryptedstring = Convert.ToBase64String(outputbuffer);

        return IVstring + encryptedstring;
    }

    public static string DecryptFratamus(this string txt) 
    {
        GenerateIVByets();
        GenerateKeys();

        int endOfIvBytes = IVbytes.Length/2;

        string ivString = txt.Substring(0, endOfIvBytes);
        byte[] extractedBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ivString);

        string encryptedString = txt.Substring(endOfIvBytes);

        SymmetricAlgorithm alg = Aes.Create();

        ICryptoTransform trans = alg.CreateDecryptor(KEYbytes, extractedBytes);

        byte[] input = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);
        byte[] output = trans.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);

        string decrypted = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(output);

        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

i've tried changing from write/read all text to the stream writer to see if it was maybe some writing error in the process but with no success

(yes, i've already tried changing the key)

Comment: Removing `rnd.NextBytes(IVbytes);` from `GenerateIVByets` fixes it. I'd guess it's something about the bytes generated representing in chars doesn't always have expected length, making the substring part goes weird.

Comment: thanks man, that fixed it

Comment: If you simply removed it, then the encryption part is gone and your savefile is basically base64 now. Removing it is merely for checking what part has the problem, not a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting funny characters when decrypting, is because the `IVstring` gets corrupted.

- The code takes random IV bytes and pretend is is valid Unicode bytes. And not all bytes are valid Unicode. You'd be better off storing the IV bytes as-is (or use base64, to follow your method for storing the encrypted bytes).
- When you re-read the `IVstring` from the file, you get a different value for some of the characters only. (Try outputing the `IVstring` when you encrypt, and when you decrypt, to see for yourself.)
- I would store both the IV and encrypted text using the same encodig. That is, either store everything binary (as-is), or use base64 on both. If using base64, you could separate them with a period (.), just like [JWT](https://jwt.io/) tokens do.

However, your code has a few issues from a security standpoint.

- First of all, never use the *pseudo random* generator `System.Random` when dealing with encryption, always use [RandomNumberGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-7.0) from `System.Security.Cryptography`.
- Remove `GenerateIVByets()` from `DecryptFratamus()`, since you are *extracting* the IV from the encrypted cipher text. (Which is correct behaviour. It just fails for some bytes in your implementation.)
- Personally, I would prefer *returning* the IV and key bytes, and not setting a static member of the class.  (Which one could read from anywhere on the code. Use `static byte[] GenerateIVByets()` instead.)

The `static byte[] GenerateKeys()` is flawed. The actual implementation will depend on how you store the secret password/key, and the level of security you need.

- The current implementation uses a "password" `"i ain't giving you the key"` to seed a pseudo random generator.
- You'd be better off using a proper hash function on the secret key to get the byte array.
- If the "importance" is *just* to encrypt a save file, a quick hash function such as SHA1 might be good enough.
- If you need better security, you'd better choose a slow hash function such as *bcrypt* or *Argon2*, which were created to withstand brute-force attacks.
- The real problem lies in how you store the secret key itself. This implementation stores `"i ain't giving you the key"` as a plain string, that can easily be read from the final .exe file. (Here, again, will it depend on the level of security you need.)
- If you expect a user to be able to enter the secret password, you should Normalize the Unicode string before hashing it:

  `string pw = "i ain't giving you the key";`

  `byte[] KEYbytes = SHA1.HashData(UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pw.Normalize()));`
- The last problem I see, is the encrypted file is *"mallable"*. That means that you can flip a bit in the saved encrypted file, and decrypt will still work. You are using Aes.Create() which uses AES CBC mode by default. (With CBC, you cannot successfully flip *any* byte, but there are still no safeguarding built into CBC.)
- Is you use [AES-GCM](https://www.scottbrady91.com/c-sharp/aes-gcm-dotnet) `AesGcm()`, the decrypt method will detect if the encrypted file has been modified.
- Is you decide to use AES-GCM it is absolutely crucial that you have a NEW random *IV* each and every time. (As long as the secret key stays teh same.) Otherwise the GCM-method will fail. IV in this case is normally called *nonce*, (n-once, only to be used *once*).
- A remedy for this is using the newer algorithm AES-GCM-SIV, that calculates an IV/nonce based on the plain text data. Unfortunaltely, it is not yet part of the standard .Net library. Another drawback with this algorithm, is that two identical plain text PlayerData objects will encrypt to two identical encrypted files. (Somtimes this is a critical drawback, sometimes it is unimportant, and sometimes this is a benefit. Depending on the situation.)

Sorry, long answer.

**Too long; Didn't read**
If you just want to make it difficult for people to edit the save file, just fix the corrupted `IVstring` mention initially. You'll be fine.

If you want to learn more about encryption. Read the list, and choose which you'd like to try out, and learn more about.

Happy coding!
Enjoy learning! :)

Comment: I really can't tank you enough man, you single-handedly taught me encryption, encoding and at the same time fixed the problems with my script, absolute legend.